# MVC - file upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

Hey...
I have upload control on my view. Is there a way to associate this control with model data(something like LabelFor or TextBoxFor). I need this, because on page load I loose my information in file upload control
Thx

Answer (score 8):

**HTML Upload File ASP MVC 3.**

**Model**: (*Note that FileExtensionsAttribute is available in MvcFutures. It will validate file extensions client side and server side.*)

```
public class ViewModel
{
    [Required, Microsoft.Web.Mvc.FileExtensions(Extensions = "csv", ErrorMessage = "Specify a CSV file. (Comma-separated values)")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

**HTML View**:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.File)
}
```

**Controller action**:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(ViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Use your file here
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            model.File.InputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the HttpPostedFileBase class for the property type and it will bind just like any other property would.

Comment: I still have the same problem, value in uploadfile is lost when page is reloaded

Comment: Have you got enctype="multipart/form-data" set? (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-enctype)